# Best way to migrate from physical to virtual using Xen on Ubuntu?

Tags: virtualization, xen, migration

I have a machine running 8.04 LTS that I would like to migrate to using Xen. There seems to be a dearth of information on how to do this without having to wipe the entire machine.

I do have another machine available to host things on if that helps. So the current state is

server001
server002

I would like to get to

server001

- virtual server001
- virtual server002

Leaving me free to decommission the physical server002.

Answer (score 1):

Directly from [XenSource](http://docs.xensource.com/XenServer/4.0.1/guest/ch02s04.html):

> To P2V an existing Linux server
> directly to a XenServer Host
>
> 1. Reboot the physical server that you want to convert and boot from the
>    XenServer installation CD. If the boot
>    fails, start again and use the
>    p2v-legacy option.
> 2. After the initial boot messages, you will see the "Welcome to
>    XenServer" screen. (In this and the
>    screens that follow, use Tab or
>    Alt+Tab to move between elements,
>    Space to select, and F12 to move to
>    the next screen.)
>
>    Select OK to proceed.
> 3. The installer does some hardware detection and initialization, then
>    presents a screen with four choices.
>
>    Select Convert an existing OS on this machine to a VM (P2V) and choose
>    OK to proceed.
> 4. A "Welcome to XenServer P2V" screen with a descriptive message is
>    displayed next. Click OK to proceed
>    and follow the on-screen prompts.
>
> When the P2V process is complete and
> the new VM is created, you will need
> to create and attach a VIF for it to
> have external network connectivity.
> Similarly, extra disks may also be
> added to take advantage of additional
> storage capacity available to the
> XenServer host.

Comment: Additionally, I did find this http://community.citrix.com/blogs/citrite/anilma/2008/07/02/Installing+Ubuntu+on+XenServer but what's the difference between XenServer and what already comes on Ubuntu 8.04?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd think they're more or less the same.

Comment: XenServer is the semi-commercial (there's a free version including most features, minus some management extras) "official" release from Citrix/XenSource.  It comes packaged as an installable hypervisor and is intended for server-type virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

This no longer applies to XenServer after release 5.5. The P2V option on the install CD has been removed.

Comment: Is there an up-to-date alternative you can provide? Free rep if so :-)